# POSTGRES - superuser can't access pg_authid table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds

Have RDS postgres instance and checked user access like this:

```
SELECT 
      r.rolname, 
      ARRAY(SELECT b.rolname
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members m
            JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles b ON (m.roleid = b.oid)
            WHERE m.member = r.oid) as memberof
FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles r
WHERE r.rolname NOT IN ('pg_signal_backend','rds_iam',
                        'rds_replication','rds_superuser',
                        'rdsadmin','rdsrepladmin')
ORDER BY 1;
```

and user X is in **{rds_superuser}** yet when I run

```
SELECT * FROM pg_authid;
```

getting

```
ERROR: permission denied for relation pg_authid
```

Tried `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE pg_authid TO vanare;`

Any ideas what I am missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pg_audit` contains database passwords, hence it has restrictive permissions:

```
\dp pg_catalog.pg_authid
                                     Access privileges
   Schema   |   Name    | Type  |     Access privileges     | Column privileges | Policies 
------------+-----------+-------+---------------------------+-------------------+----------
 pg_catalog | pg_authid | table | postgres=arwdDxt/postgres |                   | 
(1 row)
```

So only a superuser can access that table.  Contrary to intuition, `rds_superuser` is no superuser — on a hosted database, you'll never get superuser privileges, because that would allow you to access the operating system.

But you can get at all information except the password if you use the `pg_roles` view instead, which can be read by everyone.